# Excel - Mix multiple columns into one column

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns

```
          Column 1 Column 2
row 1:       A        1
row 2:       B        2
row 3:       C        3
```

I want to mix column like this

```
          Column 1 
row 1:       A      
row 2:       1        
row 3:       B
row 4:       2
row 5:       C
row 6:       3
```

I tried many examples but none of them worked.I am newbie to `vba`. Please help
I tried one below from another stack overflow example.but it will add only on last cell off column.I don't know how to change it.

```
Sub CombineColumns()
Dim rng As Range
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim lastCell As Integer

Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
lastCell = rng.Columns(1).Rows.Count + 1

For iCol = 2 To rng.Columns.Count
    Range(Cells(1, iCol), Cells(rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count, iCol)).Cut
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Cells(lastCell, 1)
    lastCell = lastCell + rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count
Next iCol
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need VBA for this.  You can use a formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$3,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/2)+1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,2)+1),"")
```

Adjust the array_range to what your data really is, and fill down.

Comment: thanks It is working.Where can i add array range?.Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @wondersofnature `array` is the first argument of the `Index` function.  `Range` refers to the cells that comprise that range.  For a discussion of Ranges, and how to refer to them, see Help for **Range**.  For a discussion of the `Index` function, see Help for that function.

Answer (score 2):

While Ros answer is quite elegant, in the sense it does not use VBA, I leave the answer using VBA, since the question is regarding VBA.

The following code assumes column 1 and 2 are columns A and B of the worksheet and that the ActiveCell is Cell A1. The output is on column C.

```
Sub CombineColumns()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iCell As Integer

    Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

    Dim iCell As Integer
    For iCell = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
        Range("C1").Offset(iCell - 1, 0) = rng.Item(iCell)
    Next iCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula and drag it down.

```
=OFFSET($A$1,(EVEN(ROW(A6))-2)/2,MOD(ROW(A6)-1,2))
```

where A1 is your 1st cell. In the above example location of "A"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so with VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Mix()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
Dim Lastrow As Long, Arr1() As Variant, Arr2() As Variant
Dim n As Long, a As Long

With ws

Lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng1 = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(Lastrow, "A"))
Set Rng2 = .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(Lastrow, "B"))

Arr1 = Rng1.Value2
Arr2 = Rng2.Value2

n = 1
For i = LBound(Arr1, 1) To UBound(Arr1, 1)
    .Cells(n, "A") = Arr1(i, 1)
    n = n + 2
Next i

a = 2
For j = LBound(Arr2, 1) To UBound(Arr2, 1)
    .Cells(a, "A") = Arr2(j, 1)
a = a + 2
Next j

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your VBA solution will run faster if, instead of populating the cells directly, you declared another array (eg `Dim Arr3(1 to Ubound(Arr1,1)*2, 1 to 1)`, populated that array, and then wrote that array back to the worksheet in a single step  (eg `Cells(1,"C").resize(ubound(Arr3,1)).value = arr3`)

Comment: You could combine the for-loops by stepping by 2 so `For i = 2 To UBound(Arr1, 1)*2 Step 2` then use `.Cells(i-1, "A") = Arr1(i/2, 1)` and `.Cells(i, "A") = Arr2(i/2, 1)`  

Or you could just eliminate the extra counters by using `.Cells(i*2, "A")` and `.Cells(j*2, "A")`

Comment: Thank for your advices